# ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE intent crashes with "Unfortunately, Gallery has stopped." after updating Nexus 7 to Android 4.3

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I'm using ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE intent to record video from camera in my app.
It works fine on previous versions of Android OS, but after updating to 4.3 it no longer works. I'm testing this on a **Nexus 7** tablet.

When I start the intent preview from camera is displayed on the screen for a brief moment and after that intent window closes with "Unfortunately, Gallery has stopped." message on the screen.

I have tried to use default settings for the intent and I have also tried specifying the output file path through EXTRA_OUTPUT setting. There is no difference in my case.

I get these lines in the trace:

> 09-13 10:24:33.908: E/NvOmxCamera(124): OMX_ERRORTYPE android::NvOmxCamera::getCameraStereoMode(NvxComponent*, NvOmxCameraUserStereoMode&): Error: invalid NVX mode 0.
>   09-13 10:24:33.908: E/NvOmxCamera(124): OMX_ERRORTYPE android::NvOmxCamera::getCameraStereoModeAndCaptureInfo(NvxComponent*, NvOmxCameraUserStereoMode&, NVX_STEREOCAPTUREINFO&): getCameraStereoMode failed with 0x00000000

And then:

> 09-13 10:24:34.348: E/AndroidRuntime(2923): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-238
>   09-13 10:24:34.348: E/AndroidRuntime(2923): java.lang.RuntimeException: startPreview failed
>   09-13 10:24:34.348: E/AndroidRuntime(2923):   at com.android.camera.VideoModule.startPreview(VideoModule.java:867)

I have also noticed that ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent works fine. And ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE intent also works fine after running ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE, until I restart the device.

Does anyone else have this problem? Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is fixed in Android 4.4.2